# Jenkins 2.289.1 Upgrade Read Permission

Tags: jenkins

I just updated Jenkins using the automatic upgrade to version 2.289.1. Everything was working absolutely fine until I upgraded. Now I can't get in to revert. When I go to the home page I get the following:

[image]

When I attempt to log in I get a 403 error saying "No valid crumb was included in the request".

Digging into the logs I see this:

```
2021-06-22 19:49:58.012+0000 [id=12]    WARNING  
h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID 
5f1b24fc-2e52-43fa-81f6-e551f44c432d
hudson.security.AccessDeniedException3: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission
```

I edited the config file to set security to false and it let me in but is unsustainable because this disables all login and removes security completely.

Edit: After updating the plug-ins, I no longer got the above screen after reactivation security. Now after logging in I get a 404 servlet error, but I can manually enter localhost:8080 to bring me to the dashboard.  Any idea what is with the bad redirect?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic on SO and should be posted on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @maio290, As I noted in a prior [closed issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67981467/598141), this is the [de-facto Jenkins Support forum](https://www.jenkins.io/participate/help/).  Perhaps there should be a recommendation to Jenkins to recommend another channel for Jenkins Configuration support and this for Usage issues, but you'll never get people choosing the right channel, at least based on the calibre of some the questions. Also, this was probably the only Stack forum when Jenkins (as Hudson) first adopted it.

Comment: @tacitus86, this usually due to having sebetal session tabs open during the restart. Close all Jenkins tabs and clear any cookies for Jenkins (and/or reatart browser), go in again. Unless you used to have anonymous access.What was the prior version?

Comment: @IanW I didn't take note. I was attempting to fix a server PKIX/cert issue and testing by triggering the update. So I finally got that worked out and it triggered the update. It was probably about a year and a half old or so.

Comment: @ianw It was 2.190.2. I updated some of the plug-ins and reactivated the security. I now get a 404 after login, but can go back to localhost:8080 manually and it will bring me to the dashboard and show me as logged in.

Comment: You would have to review the [change-log](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable); that's a big jump. Lots of issues w/[plugins @2.277.1+](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.277.1). I'd have sugested go 2.190.2-> 2.263.4, update all plugins, -> 2.277.1, update plugins, disable/remove bad plugins, -> 2.289.1, update plugins. Also note: [JENKINS-62133](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62133). You also conveniently omitted what page you were going to - main page?

Comment: @ianw Yeah I just grabbed what the auto updater had available at the time. So I simply am going to the main page (localhost:8080) and am presented the login. I log in and then get the 404 (I will get the page when I can log back into the server tomorrow).

Comment: @Ianw It seems to work fine now when I logged into it today...

Answer (score 1):

Update steps are the following:

- read jenkins changelogs;
- read plugins changelogs;
- make a backup before the update;
- probably you will need to update java version;
- remove unnecessary plugins;
- update plugins;
- update jenkins;
- update plugins;
- run several jobs to check plugins are still working.